# Debug Error Thrown When Checking !str.find()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-handling

I'm learning C++. I'm developing a simple "library management" application that allows users to create an account, check out books, etc. Each book is managed using a unique text file. The text file contains three lines as follows, however the third line is the only important thing here, as it contains the owner of the book.

[image: Screenshot Of Text File]

The following code prints the contents of an additional text file that contains a list of all the books, but that shouldn't be relevant to the error. It converts the contents of the text file to a string, and then checks to see if "NA" is present. If "NA" is present, it is replaced with the current username. The file is then reopened using `ios::trunc` to wipe the file, and the new string is passed into the file. This works fine.

The issue is that when running the application, if a username is already there instead of "NA", I get a `Debug Error` that only reads `abort() has been called`. I've tried debugging, but I can't get any more information.

This is the error and the code:

[image: Error]

```
void bookCheckout()
{
    system("CLS");
    string line;
    string bookChoice;
    ifstream checkBookList;
    ofstream checkOutBook;
    checkBookList.open("books/booklist.txt");
    
    string sTotal;
    string s;

    

    cout << "<---Avaliable Books--->" << endl;
    while (getline(checkBookList, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    checkBookList.close();

    cout << "\nWhat Book Would You Like?:";
    cin >> bookChoice;

    checkBookList.open("books/" + bookChoice + ".txt");
    while (!checkBookList.eof()) {
        getline(checkBookList, s);
        sTotal += s + "\n";
    }

    checkBookList.close();
    if (sTotal.find("NA")) {
        sTotal.replace(sTotal.find("NA"), 2,  globalUsername);
        checkOutBook.open("books/" + bookChoice + ".txt", ios::trunc);
        checkOutBook << sTotal;
        checkOutBook.close();
    }
    else if (!sTotal.find("NA")) {
        
        cout << "Book already checked out!" << endl;
    }
    
    checkOutBook.close();
    


    
    system("PAUSE");

    

}
```

Comment: Your error dialog has `Retry` button; did you click it?

Comment: I pressed the Retry button and I got a box saying "Library Management System.exe has stopped working"

Comment: If you build the `Debug` configuration and run "Debug" (`F5`), that retry should take you to the place of failure.

Comment: `while (!checkBookList.eof()) {` - see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/) `if (sTotal.find("NA")) {` - `string::find()` returns an index, not a boolean. And if your goal is to find a LINE that says `"NA"`, using `find()` is not the best choice for that purpose. `else if (!sTotal.find("NA")) {` - no need to call `find()` in the `else` at all

Comment: I added the proper code and it works. Thank you so much. I'm new to C++ as I'm sure you can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

- lack of error handling.
- `while (!checkBookList.eof())` - see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)
- `if (sTotal.find("NA"))` - `string::find()` returns an INDEX, not a BOOLEAN. If 0 is returned, that will be evaluated as false. All other values will be evaluated as true, including `string::npos` (-1), which is what `string::find()` returns if a match is not found.

Also, your goal is to check if the *3RD LINE SPECIFICALLY* is `"NA"`, so using `string::find()` is not the best choice for that purpose. Think of what would happen if the 1st or 2nd line happened to *contain* the letters `NA`. Your code logic would not behave properly.

- `else if (!sTotal.find("NA"))` - no need to call `find()` in the `else` at all.  Just use `else` by itself.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
void bookCheckout()
{
    system("CLS");

    ifstream checkBookList;

    checkBookList.open("books/booklist.txt");
    if (!checkBookList.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Unable to open booklist.txt" << endl;
        return;
    }

    string line;

    cout << "<---Available Books--->" << endl;
    while (getline(checkBookList, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    checkBookList.close();

    cout << "\nWhat Book Would You Like?:";

    string bookChoice;
    getline(cin, bookChoice);

    checkBookList.open("books/" + bookChoice + ".txt");
    if (!checkBookList.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Unable to open " + bookChoice + ".txt for reading" << endl;
        return;
    }

    string sTotal, sOwner;
    int lineNum = 0;
    string::size_type ownerIndex = string::npos;

    while (getline(checkBookList, line)) {
        ++lineNum;
        if (lineNum == 3) {
            sOwner = line;
            ownerIndex = sTotal.size();
        }
        sTotal += line + "\n";
    }

    checkBookList.close();

    if (sOwner == "NA") {
        sTotal.replace(ownerIndex, 2, globalUsername);

        ofstream checkOutBook("books/" + bookChoice + ".txt", ios::trunc);
        if (!checkOutBook.is_open()) {
            cerr << "Unable to open " + bookChoice + ".txt for writing" << endl;
            return;
        }

        checkOutBook << sTotal;
        checkOutBook.close();

        cout << "Book checked out!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Book already checked out by " << sOwner << "!" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Alternatively, use a `std::vector` to gather the book contents, that will give you indexed access to each line:

```cpp
#include <vector>

void bookCheckout()
{
    system("CLS");

    ifstream checkBookList;

    checkBookList.open("books/booklist.txt");
    if (!checkBookList.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Unable to open booklist.txt" << endl;
        return;
    }

    string line;

    cout << "<---Available Books--->" << endl;
    while (getline(checkBookList, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    checkBookList.close();

    cout << "\nWhat Book Would You Like?:";

    string bookChoice;
    getline(cin, bookChoice);

    checkBookList.open("books/" + bookChoice + ".txt");
    if (!checkBookList.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Unable to open " + bookChoice + ".txt for reading" << endl;
        return;
    }

    vector<string> sTotal;
    sTotal.reserve(3);

    while (getline(checkBookList, line)) {
        sTotal.push_back(line);
    }

    while (sTotal.size() < 3) {
        sTotal.push_back("");
    }

    checkBookList.close();

    if (sTotal[2] == "" || sTotal[2] == "NA") {
        sTotal[2] = globalUsername;

        ofstream checkOutBook("books/" + bookChoice + ".txt", ios::trunc);
        if (!checkOutBook.is_open()) {
            cerr << "Unable to open " + bookChoice + ".txt for writing" << endl;
            return;
        }

        for(size_t i = 0; i < sTotal.size(); ++i) {
            checkOutBook << sTotal[i] << '\n';
        }
        checkOutBook.close();

        cout << "Book checked out!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Book already checked out by " << sTotal[2] << "!" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to recode this a few times to really cement it in my brain.